# auto and copy constructor: what's wrong?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, auto

Consider the following code:

```
#include<queue>
#include<type_traits>

int main() {
    std::queue<int> q;
    auto p{q};
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(q), decltype(p)>::value, "fail");
}
```

It compiles fine with *GCC 5.1.0* (see [here](https://godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g510,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11',source:'%23include%3Cqueue%3E%0A%23include%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++std::queue%3Cint%3E+q%3B%0A++auto+p%7Bq%7D%3B%0A++static_assert(std::is_same%3Cdecltype(q),+decltype(p)%3E::value,+%22fail%22)%3B%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)) and *clang 3.8.0* (see [here](https://godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang380,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11',source:'%23include%3Cqueue%3E%0A%23include%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++std::queue%3Cint%3E+q%3B%0A++auto+p%7Bq%7D%3B%0A++static_assert(std::is_same%3Cdecltype(q),+decltype(p)%3E::value,+%22fail%22)%3B%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)), but it doesn't with *GCC 4.9.0* (see [here](https://godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g490,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11',source:'%23include%3Cqueue%3E%0A%23include%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++std::queue%3Cint%3E+q%3B%0A++auto+p%7Bq%7D%3B%0A++static_assert(std::is_same%3Cdecltype(q),+decltype(p)%3E::value,+%22fail%22)%3B%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)).
From a further analysis, it seems to be due to the fact that the type of `p` is deduced as `std::initializer_list`.
As an example, it works if one substitutes the line:

```
auto p{q};
```

With the line:

```
decltype(q) p{q};
```

I'm not sure which one is right (even though *GCC 5.1.0* works according with my expectations) and that's why I've asked here.
Is it right to expect the type of `p` to be `std::queue<int>`?

Comment: This is exceptional situation. Mayers wrote about this in the "Effective modern C++" for C++11/14.
This is due to a special type deduction rule for auto. When the initializer for an
auto-declared variable is enclosed in braces, the deduced type is a std::initial
izer_list. If such a type can’t be deduced (e.g., because the values in the braced ini‐
tializer are of different types)

Comment: auto is c++11 feature and as far as I know it's fully supported in gcc only from 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a known defect in the standard](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3681.html) that `auto` deduces `{}` as `std::initializer_list`. [There is a proposed change to fix this defect](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html).

Newer gcc and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) implement the proposed resolution, whereas gcc-4.9 does not.

Answer (score 0):

No.
`{q}` evaluates to `std::initializer_list`. There's nothing to tell the compiler you might want something else so auto uses that one.

Also `decltype(q)` is not the same as `decltype({q})`;